# How to recognise intel graphic card in GLSL program?

Tags: opengl, glsl, intel

On Nvidia cards, if you want clip plane is enabled, gl_ClipVertex must be assigned in glsl program. But on Ati cards, there is a problem if gl_ClipVertex is assigned.

For Nvidia/Ati compatibility, we write codes like this:

```
// fix the clipping bug for both Nvidia and Ati   
#ifdef __GLSL_CG_DATA_TYPES
    gl_ClipVertex = gl_ModelViewMatrix*gl_Vertex;
#endif
```

You can check this [link](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/451347-clip-plane--reflection-problem/) for more information.

There is a problem. On intel graphic cards (e.g. HD Graphics 3000), gl_GlipVertex must be assigned too. If not, the clip plane is useless. But as we know, __GLSL_CG_DATA_TYPES is only defined on a Nvidia system. So the gl_ClipVertex line is skippd on intel. Now it seems hard to write compatible glsl programs both right on Nvidia/Ati/Intel cards.

Is there something like __GLSL_CG_DATA_TYPES can recognise intel graphic card in GLSL program?

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you're talking about a bug workaround. Well, the only real way to work around this is to `#define` `__GLSL_CG_DATA_TYPES` yourself from *outside* the shader (ie: inserting the string into the shader). Better yet, create your own `#define` that you insert into the shader string, after the `#version` declaration.

How you go about inserting the string into the shader is up to you. You could do some simple parsing of GLSL, finding the first non-comment line after the `#version` directive and doing the insertion there.

From outside the shader, you'll have to use the `GL_RENDERER` and `GL_VENDOR` strings to detect whether you should provide the `#define` or not.

Comment: Yes,Thanks, It's an available solution. But it would be better if there is a GLSL define that Intel always sets and no one else does. What I say is a symbol define by compiler or driver, not by ourselves. Do you know any one?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Nicol you will have to detect the hardware outside the shader and pass in a define. You can pass additional defines when compiling the shader:

```
const char *vertSrcs[2] = { "#define INTEL\n", vShaderSrc };
glShaderSource(vId, 2, vertSrcs, NULL);
```

something like this should work.

Comment: *"something like this should work."* - It shouldn't in general, since `#version` needs to be the first (non-empty) line of a shader. But Ok, from the use of deprecated functionality in his example he probably isn't even aware of any version and uses good old 1.10.